# How to prevent the quick-release pin on the Tektro drop brake lever from rattling?

Tags: brakes, handlebars, noise, brake-noise

[Tektro RL-340 brake levers](http://www.tektro.com/_english/01_products/01_prodetail.php?pid=67&sortname=Lever&sort=1&fid=3) have a quick release mechanism that, when pushed in, will lengthen the cable to allow to easily [disengage the brake from the wheel/disc](http://www.tektro.com/_english/02_technology/01_detail.php?pid=3) without needing to deflate the tire.

[image]

It's not a big deal, in fact, it's nothing bad, just a little annoying and interesting:

When the brakes pressed when riding, the pin rattles — is there any way to stop that?

Has anyone disassembled the levers before?

Comment: I have the same problem. I dripped some loctite onto the shaft to hold it tight/disable it, but I don't use the QR feature.

Comment: I would think there would be several glue-like compounds you could use -- several that would be more easily reversed than Loctite.

Comment: Some thick grease would probably muffle the sound a bit, while still allowing you to use the quick release feature.

Comment: I've heard (strangely) that the rattling goes away over time (though it might just be people's brains tuning it out). YMMV.

Comment: @Batman I have about 6500 miles on these levers and can say that they have only gotten worse over time. I even dropped in some liquid nails to try and lock them in place to prevent rattle. This only lasted a short time before coming loose again and rattling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my levers I use tight rubber O-rings. I did them myself out of old tube.
This levers are easy to disassemble — to get QR pins out just press on them.