# How to reduce brake lever rattling sound at the pivot pin either by a fix or by replacement?

Tags: shimano, hydraulic-disc-brake, brake-levers

#### Context

I have a [Merida Speeder 200](https://www.merida-bikes.com/en/bike/78/SPEEDER+200) with a Shimano MT-200 hydraulic brake system, which uses [BL-MT200 levers](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/acera-m390/BL-MT200.html).

Over time these levers have developed a rattling sound. It appears to come from the lever rattling against its housing at the pivot point. Intuitively I would tighten the pivot bolt, but it appears to be a rivet, so I can't really do anything with it.

#### Things I've looked into

The answer to [this related question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/15902/6852) mentions using an o-ring, but because of the rivet-like pivot I can't disassemble the lever.

The sound can be damped easily by just resting my fingers on the levers, but I sometimes prefer to just hold the bar without my fingers on the lever.

#### Question

Can I silence these rattling levers? Or is there perhaps a compatible lever that does not rattle?

Comment: Any chance to tighten the rivet? Maybe just by compressing it slightly in a vice?

Comment: Maybe a thick grease pressed into the pivot? Something that will lubricate but also stay in place and dampen the vibrations?

Comment: @Michael Bad idea in my opinion. It's not a true rivet, more of a press-fit pin. You wouldn't achieve much, and you risk cracking the lever body.

Comment: Further to @NateW suggestion, some grease in between the lever and the pin would help, but maybe so would grease or a fibre washer between the lever and the body of the  brake.  Depends what is rattling on what.

Comment: It may be possible to make a new pin, but these are brakes and they absolutely must work when needed.  If the rattling annoys you enough, replace the levers.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the possibility of replacing, but I'm not sure what feature I should look for in a lever that "provides" silence.

Comment: This is a general issue: moving things made with closed parts, without having in mind the possibilty of disassembling/rebuilding an item, then things will start to have play issues. On the other hand, making things adjustable, it can be demanding.
Everything was fine for you, until small wearing of the riveted parts promoted some play and now you have some rattling.
A lever which can be tighten/looesened/disassembled would provides a permanent solution. 
Even the MT201, equal to yours, but with an aluminium lever, claims by the producer to have "Less pad rattling noise" shorturl.at/stAR4

Comment: Thanks @EarlGrey for the MT201 suggestion, but it appears that they refer to pad rattling noise of the brake system due to wider pad-disc clearance. The same text is also included on the MT200 page. If you're aware of a compatible lever that can be tightened at the pivot, could you please add it to your answer?

Comment: Any Shimano lever is compatible. The one-finger levers have springs on the lever blade to stop them from rattling, and the lever blades are replaceable (you can add shims or something if they do rattle).

Answer (score 3):

The lever of this specific model is not replaceable. So you can try your luck with a thick grease, or by "inserting" some layer of foam, or gluing little patches of old tubes in between the lever and the housing, close to the rivet.

The rattling is happening because of some play between the parts. The weight of your finger is enough to keep the parts in contact ---> replicate that by putting some material in between.